# QGIS break polyline into line segments

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

In QGIS (2.14.3.) how do I break polyline features in their consisting (single)line features? I have tried the 'Explode lines' geoprocessing tool, but this destroys the whole polyline into very atomic lines consisting of only start- and endpoint.

This visualizes what I have in mind (offset in start/endpoints only for visualisatin purposes):

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent of http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html ?

Comment: It seems that while you are asking for the lines to be split into simple lines, the result you want is actually arbitrary based on points you specify.  The `Explode` tool breaks the lines into their child segments, which are known.  If you want to break lines into smaller segments, but larger than the individual, straight-line segments, you may need something like [postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html), which allows you to specify the break points along the line.

Comment: Or the `Multipart to Singleparts` tool tin QGIS (Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Multipart to Singleparts)